# Changing a css variable in styled components from a React props

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid, styled-components, emotion

I am using CSS grid to create a dynamic table. The number of columns and rows are dynamic and are based on props I get from an higher component in React.

How can I change a css variable inside a styled component (emotion) to the data I get from a React props?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is in their documentation:
https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props

```
// Create an Input component that'll render an <input> tag with some styles
const Input = styled.input`
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  color: ${props => props.inputColor || "palevioletred"};
  background: papayawhip;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;

// Render a styled text input with the standard input color, and one with a custom input color
render(
  <div>
    <Input defaultValue="@probablyup" type="text" />
    <Input defaultValue="@geelen" type="text" inputColor="rebeccapurple" />
  </div>
);
```